# Displaying API response - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

In my app the user pastes an image URL, clicks on a button, the app requests API information about the picture. The API responds with an Array of info which I want to display in the browser. I'm getting the response (can confirm with console.log) but cannot find the best way of displaying it. 
I'm thinking about another component file of IngredientsList.

Any to get me in the right direction, please?

Thanks in advance

**APP.JS**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Clarifai from 'clarifai'
import Navigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation'
import FoodRecognition from './components/Food_recognition/Food_recognition'
import Logo from './components/Logo/Logo'
import IngredientsList from './components/IngredientsList/IngredientsList'
import ImageLinkForm from './components/ImageLinkForm/ImageLinkForm'
import Signin from './components/Signin/Signin'
import Register from './components/Register/Register'
import './App.css'

const app = new Clarifai.App({
  apiKey: '6382df74e5c243f589fff9057a7e41bd'
 });


class App extends Component {
  constructor()  {
    super()
    this.state = {
      input: '',
      imageUrl: '',
      route: 'signin',
      isSignedIn: false
    }
  }

  onInputChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({input: event.target.value})

  }

  onButtonSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({imageUrl: this.state.input})
    app.models
    .predict( 
      Clarifai.FOOD_MODEL,
      this.state.input)
      .then(
    function(response) {
      console.log(response)
    },
    function(err) {
    }
  );
  }

onRouteChange = (route) => {
  if (route === 'signout') {
    this.setState({isSignedIn: false})
  } else if (route === 'home') {
    this.setState({isSignedIn: true})
  }
this.setState({route: route})
}

  render() { 
    const { isSignedIn, imageUrl, route } = this.state
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navigation isSignedIn={this.state.isSignedIn}onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
        {route === 'home'
          ? <div>
            <Logo />
            <IngredientsList />
            <ImageLinkForm
              onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
              onButtonSubmit={this.onButtonSubmit} />
            <FoodRecognition imageUrl={imageUrl} />
          </div>
          : (
            route === 'signin'
              ? <Signin onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
              : <Register onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
          )
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You can save the response and either display it within this component or pass the value as props to another component, depends on what you want to do before thinking of the solution

Comment: Maybe it's better to pass it as props to another component in a different file since I want that information to be reusable in the future. Any hint about how should I do it?

Comment: I would advise you to read https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html 

It explains hows props works you should find everything you need from A to Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular way of doing this is after getting your response, setting it to your state. You can pass this response to which component you want.

In the below code I just added a state property named `resposne`, then in your fetch method I set the state with the response, then pass this state to your component in the render method. In the first render, the `response` value will be an empty array, after fetching and updating your state it will pass the real data to your component in the second render.

```
const app = new Clarifai.App({
  apiKey: '6382df74e5c243f589fff9057a7e41bd'
 });


class App extends Component {
  constructor()  {
    super()
    this.state = {
      input: '',
      imageUrl: '',
      route: 'signin',
      isSignedIn: false,
      response: [],
    }
  }

  onInputChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({input: event.target.value})

  }

  onButtonSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({imageUrl: this.state.input})
    app.models
    .predict( 
      Clarifai.FOOD_MODEL,
      this.state.input)
      .then( response => this.setState( {response } ) );
  }

onRouteChange = (route) => {
  if (route === 'signout') {
    this.setState({isSignedIn: false})
  } else if (route === 'home') {
    this.setState({isSignedIn: true})
  }
this.setState({route: route})
}

  render() { 
    const { isSignedIn, imageUrl, route } = this.state
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navigation isSignedIn={this.state.isSignedIn}onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
        {route === 'home'
          ? <div>
            <Logo />
            <IngredientsList response={this.state.response} />
            <ImageLinkForm
              onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
              onButtonSubmit={this.onButtonSubmit} />
            <FoodRecognition imageUrl={imageUrl} />
          </div>
          : (
            route === 'signin'
              ? <Signin onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
              : <Register onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
          )
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Update after comments**

Mapping your data is the easiest part.

```js
const App = props => {
  function renderData() {
    return props.data.map(item =>
      <div key={item.id}>
        <p>Name: {item.name}</p>
        <p>Age: {item.age} </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
  
  return (
    <div>{renderData()}</div>
  );
}

const data = [
  { id: 1, name: "foo", age: 25 },
  { id: 2, name: "bar", age: 35 },
  { id: 3, name: "baz", age: 45 },
]

ReactDOM.render(<App data={data} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Got it! I've passed to my other component and I can console.log it. Now I need to map over the array and display the objects I want in some UI. Any hints? Thanks btw!

Comment: I've updated my answer. Mapping is easy. I also agree with reading the official documentation suggestion :)

Comment: I was just getting stuck on how to map over the array since it comes from an API. But now I got the idea, will work around this;) Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Welcome to SO :)